# How do I know when qcs-sensor has completed it's scan

Tags: qualys

I am running `qualys/qcs-sensor:latest --cicd-deployed-sensor` in CICD mode.

Is there an API I can use to find out when `qcs-sensor` has completed it's scans and has uploaded the scan results to Qualys servers?

I tried the show details of an image API
`GET 'https://gateway.qg1.apps.qualys.com/csapi/v1.3/images/:imageSha'`
However, this may return the results of a previous CICD scan